# sailsjs can't find a route 'myroute/:id'

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I have a route in sails JS configured as this:

```
'get /company/ranking/:id': {controller: 'CompanyController', action: 'getRanking'}
```

In my local environment works perfect, calls the `CompanyController` and calls the `getRanking` action. The problem is in production, it will throw a 404 error telling that it doesn't find the endpoint.

Any advice with this?

Comment: are you running production locally or is your production on another server?

Comment: production is on another server

Comment: Asking for Advice makes your question seem a little too broad and vague. I would update it to include your production environment specs and how you are publishing to production.

Comment: Can you give us the contents of the error, what gets logged when run in `--verbose` mode, and your sails version?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, forever was running as a super super, and the script to deploy didn't have sudo before. Updated the server so it doesn't require sudo. Now the changes are applying.